# Как разработать базовый интерфейс на Flutter с null знаний

Tags: flutter, мобильная-разработка, фреймворк, flutter-ui

Меня записали на хакатон, сначала говорили, что будет где-то в Ноябре, сейчас сказали, что он будет 20 Октября.
В Хакатоне у нас 3 участника, дизайнер, разраб(я), менеджер.
Вот только загвоздка в том, что я не умею работать на Flutter, я только начал его изучать и знаю поверхностно, некоторые аргументы, виджеты, где подключать библиотеки. Но вот сверстать даже самое говняное приложение я не смогу, может кто посоветует, что-то, чтобы быстро сократить обучение (Только самое основное для построение интерфейса), ну или шаблоны для приложений на Flutter, не хочу просто сказать всем, что я ничего не знаю, поэтому делать ничего не буду

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужны самые быстрые способы, построение плохого, но хотя бы работающего интерфейса на Flutter, мне нужны либо темы, которые я могу изучить за день и построить такой интерфейс, либо шаблоны с GitGUB для приложений

Comment: Flutter на практике (ISBN 978-5-97060-808-1) более-менее раскрывает простую вёрстку и основные компоненты. Лучший способ быстро влиться - верстать на практике + плюс гуглить всё, что не понимается. https://habr.com/ru/articles/500210/ - эта статья обязательна к прочтению до полного понимания.